# Programmitically how to create task scheduler in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

In windows application, when i import the task scheduler(.job format) in windows XP machine it is working fine. but when i am trying to import the task scheduler in windows server 2008 it is not importing. It throws format is not valid because .job format was not supported by Windows server 2008. Could you provide any solution to solve

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows Vista, the [task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756979.aspx)  is vastly improved, but it is incompatible with the .job files from the old version (and there doesn't appear to exist a conversion tool).

However, you can access it from scripts like VBScript or Powershell or control it via a CLI tool called `schtasks.exe`.